# How can replace this url

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

i need to change this url like second one how can i replace first code like second one?

```
<td><a href="<?php echo $this->get_user_link( $user->ID ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'View Profile', 'wpuf-pro' ); ?></a></td>
```

to

```
echo '<span><a href="' . get_site_url() . '/author/' . $user->user_login . '"><img src="' . $author_avatar_url . '"></a></span>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to create a php string that will output the first code example?
If yes than you can do this

```
echo '<td><a href="' . $this->get_user_link($user->ID) . '">' . esc_html__('View Profile', 'wpuf-pro' ) . '</a></td>';
```